# calling OKTA url from Angular app gives 404 but works in browser

Tags: angular, okta, okta-api

i am having a scenario where i have to call an OKTA url "{}/api/v1/sessions/me" in an angular app. 
i am not using any library just making a plain get call. 
i am using a code like this

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
this.http
  .get<SessionInfo[]>(`https://xxx.xxx.com/api/v1/sessions/me`, { headers })
  .subscribe((data: SessionInfo[]) => {
    alert(data);
  });
```

and the SessionInfo looks like this

```
export class SessionInfo {
userId: string;
login: string;
  }
```

when i run the url in browser i get the proper response.

[image]

before that i was having a CORS issue but i fixed it in the okta dashboard and added localhost:8080 in CORS list. after that i am getting 404.

Any ideas ?

**update**
https://devforum.okta.com/t/get-current-session-api-not-returning-session/3758
discussion here makes me believe that it has something to do with cookies. my goals is to pick up current user's ID but looks like we cannot read cookies form another url.

**update 2**
i made a simple html page and host it using simple nodejs server i do get a response. and doing same from angular i get 404

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I matched the header of index.html and header what angular was sending. index.html was sending  cookies which angular was not sending. so by setting { withCredentials: true }) Angular does the same .

```
 .get<SessionInfo>(`https://tenet.oktapreview.com/api/v1/sessions/me`, { withCredentials: true })
```